# Python: Indicate the elements in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by, enumerate

I encountered a problem to indicate the element which is not used as the grouping criteria in `groupby` .

I am expecting the output to be in the format of:

```py
{
    "0": {
          "food_type": "drink", 
          "review": "bad", 
          "example": {"0": "cola", "1": "milk"}
    },
    "1": {
         "food_type": "fruit",
         "review": "good",
         "example": {"0": "apple", "1": "banana", "2": "orange"}
    },
    "2": {
         "food_type": "vegetable", 
         "review": "normal",
         "example": {"0": "cabbage", "1": "carrot"}
    },
}
```

This is the code I used(suggested by Andrej Kesely), grouping the elements based on the element with index [0].

And I encountered some problem when trying to add more key-value pair when the `lst` grows larger. I added the `"review"` part:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [
    ["fruit", 'good', "apple"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "orange"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "banana"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "cabbage"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "carrot"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "cola"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "milk"],
]

out = {}
for i, (v, g) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(lst), lambda k: k[0])):
    out[str(i)] = {
        "food_type": v,
        "review": (v for i, (_, v, _) in enumerate(g)),
        "example": {str(i): v for i, (_, _, v) in enumerate(g)},
    }
```

The output:

```py
{
    "0": {
          "food_type": "drink", 
          "review": <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcc04f3fdd0>, 
          "example": {"0": "cola", "1": "milk"}
    },
    "1": {
         "food_type": "fruit",
         "review": <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcc04f3fc50>,
         "example": {"0": "apple", "1": "banana", "2": "orange"}
    },
    "2": {
         "food_type": "vegetable", 
         "review": <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fcc04d044d0>,
         "example": {"0": "cabbage", "1": "carrot"}
    },
}
```

Hope someone has more experience in `groupby` can give me some suggestions. Thank you!!!

Comment: What output would you expect if drinking milk was good?

Comment: Your expected and actual outputs appear to be the SAME.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Arrrrrhg! Sorry, I'm actually legally blind  but that's still not a valid excuse!

Comment: @Pychopath I am having same reviews for the same food types. (I know it doesn't make sense haha, it's just a toy example that I made out)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
lst = [
    ["fruit", 'good', "apple"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "orange"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "banana"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "cabbage"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "carrot"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "cola"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "milk"],
]


out = (
    pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=["food_type", "review", "example"])
    .groupby(["food_type", "review"])["example"].unique()
    .reset_index()
    .assign(example = lambda df: (
        df["example"].apply(lambda x: {k:v for k, v in zip(range(len(x)), x)})
    ))
    .T.to_dict()
)
```

Output:

```
{0: {'food_type': 'drink', 'review': 'bad', 'example': {0: 'cola', 1: 'milk'}},
 1: {'food_type': 'fruit',
  'review': 'good',
  'example': {0: 'apple', 1: 'orange', 2: 'banana'}},
 2: {'food_type': 'vegetable',
  'review': 'normal',
  'example': {0: 'cabbage', 1: 'carrot'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to change the generators into string we would want to use the `', '.join` function

```
"review": ', '.join(v for i, (_, v, _) in enumerate(g)),
```

But upon doing this I found that good was repeated three times and normal and bad were repeated as well. [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are often used as an easy way of storing data when you don't want duplicates. We can use [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of generator comprehension by adding some surrounding `{}` brackets. This gives us the following to be used when getting the reviews.

```
"review": ', '.join({v for i, (_, v, _) in enumerate(g)}),
```

In your data each food category always had the same type of review (either good, normal or bad). By using `', '.join`, if a category has multiple reviews, we will end up with a comma separated string. If you would rather handle multiple reviews differently let me know.

As a little quirk of `groupby`, the generator can only be used once, so we will also need to store it in a list before we loop over it.

full code:

```
from itertools import groupby
import pprint

lst = [
    ["fruit", 'good', "apple"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "orange"],
    ["fruit", 'good', "banana"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "cabbage"],
    ["vegetable", 'normal', "carrot"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "cola"],
    ["drink", 'bad', "milk"],
]

out = {}
for i, (v, g) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(lst), lambda k: k[0])):
    g = list(g)
    out[str(i)] = {
        "food_type": v,
        "review": ', '.join({x for _, x, _ in g}),
        "example": {str(i): x for i, (_, _, x) in enumerate(g)},
    }
pprint.pprint(out)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation! It is very helpful! and yes, I am having same `"reviews"` elements for the same` food_type` so that would be fine. Maybe one more confuse, I am wondering why the order of the output `out` element was shifted(`"example"` is in the first). because it is the one being enumerated? Thank you again!!

Comment: `pprint` is messing up the order, and it looks like it is doing it on purpose. Version 3.8 of Python added a new parameter to pprint that is enabled by default that sorts dictionaries before printing them. If I do `pprint.pprint(out, sort_dicts=False)`, or use the normal `print` function, then it stops shifting around elements.

Comment: @Pychopath I was using 3.7.10.

Comment: @hostingutilities.com I see!! I wrote it in a function so everything is fine now. I was just wondering the reason. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you have the same reviews for the same food types, so just take the first one. You could do this:

```
out = {}
for i, (v, [*g]) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(lst), lambda k: k[0])):
    out[str(i)] = {
        "food_type": v,
        "review": g[0][1],
        "example": {str(i): v for i, (_, _, v) in enumerate(g)},
    }
```

I made two changes:

- `[*g]`, making `g` a `list` that can be used for both `"review"` and `"example"` (you can use the generator *iterator* provided by `groupby` only *once*).
- `"review": g[0][1]`, using the first review string.